# Define $f\colon\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $f(a,b)=a-b$. Is $f$ associative?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, associativity

I have 3 questions about this question.

First of all I'm confused about the notation.

My understanding is that the first part( $f\colon\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$)  means that for any combination of 2 real number $(a,b)$, it will map to one single Real number.  The second part ($f(a,b)=a-b$) means that the mapping of $(a,b)$ will be ($a-b$).  Am I correct?

Second of all, I'm confuse about what this question is even asking.  What does define mean? How do you define a function? Isn't the function already defined in the question

Lastly, I know for example that $a-b-c$ is not associative since $(a-b)-c$ is not the same thing as $a-(b-c)$, however when we only have 1 subtraction, wouldn't it be associative by default since there is only one way to add parentheses to the function (ex.// $(a-b)$).

Comment: $$f(f(a,b),c)=(a-b)-c=a-b\color{red}-c$$$$f(a,f(b,c))=a-(b-c)=a-b\color{red}+c$$So $f$ isn't associative.

Comment: Yes, the function is already defined. But "define" a function is very common terminology -- in case the function is defined it can be taken to mean "consider" the function.

Comment: @DonThousand, I'm trying to understand what you did to show that $f$ is not associative.  It appears you swapped the values of $(a,b)$ to show their not associative.  Wouldn't that show that the function is not commutative rather then associative?

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that the first part( $f\colon\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$)  means that for any combination of 2 real number $(a,b)$, it will map to one single Real number.  The second part ($f(a,b)=a-b$) means that the mapping of $(a,b)$ will be ($a-b$).  Am I correct?

This is indeed correct. You could instead write the mapping as $(a,b) \mapsto (a-b)$.

> Second of all, I'm confuse about what this question is even asking. What does define mean? How do you define a function? Isn't the function already defined in the question

To define a function, you need to specify a domain, codomain, and definition for the mapping (what from the domain goes where in the codomain). In this case, your domain is $\Bbb R^2$, your codomain is $\Bbb R$, and your mapping is as described (ordered pairs $(a,b)$ go to $(a-b)$).

"Defining a function" in this sense basically means to describe the function in all these ways, and often attribute it a name for quick reference, e.g. $f,g,h,$ whatever.

> Lastly, I know for example that $a-b-c$ is not associative since $(a-b)-c$ is not the same thing as $a-(b-c)$, however when we only have 1 subtraction, wouldn't it be associative by default since there is only one way to add parentheses to the function (ex.// $(a-b)$).

Association is only a concern when three elements are involved. For an operation $\ast$, it is associative over the set of concern if

$$a \ast (b \ast c) = (a \ast b) \ast c$$

for all $a,b,c$ in the set of concern. This requires us to work with three elements, not simply two (as you might do in the case of showing commutativity, $a \ast b = b \ast a$).

Comment: Just to clarify your last point. Since the law of associations only applies when 3 elements are involved, are you saying that asking (is $f$ associative) is an invalid question?  @DonThousand in the comments of my original question seems to have a different way of proving that $f$ is not associative, although I don't fully understand what he did.

Comment: In this case, your "elements" are ordered pairs. If we choose to write $\ast$ as a function instead of the common notation, we would have $$x \ast y = \ast(x,y)$$ and thus associativity is given by $$\ast(a,\ast(b,c)) = \ast(\ast(a,b),c)$$ instead. What $a,b,c$ exactly are depends on the underlying set and operation. They could be individual numbers, vectors, ordered pairs, sets, functions, whatever the context dictates. For example, you could have $a = (1,1)$, an ordered pair, if the operation were over $\Bbb R$ (and thus your inputs are from $\Bbb R^2$).